# Xdebug profiling not save logs to the folder

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, xdebug, laragon

I am on windows 10 OS.

I want to use profiling , I have done some steps which articles says those are enough for Xdebug can save logs but no use I can not find any log in the mentioned folder.

I want to share my configuration with you . Please guide me even google not helped me related this.

Added lines on php.ini

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.mode = profile;
xdebug.start_with_request = yes;
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\db\xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "callgrind.out.%t-%s"
```

php.ini
[image]

alt text
I have enabled the downloaded extension on Extension section.
Even https://xdebug.org/wizard says the installation done.
Do you have any idea what is problem?

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem.

Xdebug 3 has some changes. After reviewing of the changelog, this change needs to be made:

from
`xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\Soft\laragon\www\xdebug"`
to `xdebug.output_dir="D:\Soft\laragon\www\xdebug"`

You can review all changes via [this link](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

Comment: Works for me, tnx